# How to debug a Fortran program with `-fdump-parse-tree` in gfortran?

Tags: debugging, fortran, gfortran

How to use `-fdump-parse-tree` flag to debug my program? What is the actual syntax I can put in my command line?

Comment: This is not a debugging option! What *exactly* are you trying to achieve? My recommendation is to forget this option until you understand well what a parse tree is and which purpose does it serve. It is NOT for debugging your program.

Comment: The -fdump-* options are useful mostly when developing and debugging the compiler itself. Unless you're a compiler developer, or are trying to determine whether a problem is due to a compiler bug, these options are probably not that useful.